# laravel 5 querying request loop before saving to the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Please i do have an issue i want to some multiple input field which would and save to the database but before saving i would want to go to other tables to check the quantity and some other features so that if one of the request field  fails from the loop does not meet the requirement it pulls back an error response like for example the quantity for item 5 is not enough to send

here are the code of which its sending currently to the db

```
   public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $data = $request->except('_token');

    $productName = count($data['productName']);
    for($i=0; $i < $productName; $i++){

        $stt = new StockTransferTransaction;

        $stt->stock_id = $data['productName'][$i];
        $stt->rate = $data['rate'][$i];


        $stt->quantity = $data['quantity'][$i];
        $stt->valuation = $data['totalValue'][$i];
        $stt->stock_transfer_id = $id;


        // this is where i would love to perform the quantity checks before saving 

        $stock = Stock::where('id', $productName)->get();

        dd($stock);

        $stt->save();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the **count**:
`$productName = count($data['productName']);`
as **id**
`$stock = Stock::where('id', $productName)->get();`

You can have your checks like:

```
for($i=0; $i < $productName; $i++){

  $stock = Stock::find(/*StockID*/);
  //dd($stock);

  if ($stock) {
    //Error message
  }
  else {
    $stt = new StockTransferTransaction;

    $stt->stock_id = $data['productName'][$i];
    $stt->rate = $data['rate'][$i];


    $stt->quantity = $data['quantity'][$i];
    $stt->valuation = $data['totalValue'][$i];
    $stt->stock_transfer_id = $id;

    $stt->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but the $stock = Stock::findOrFail($data['productName'][$i]); only shows one collection from the numerous collections inserted

Comment: because its the Primary key of Stock... Try `Stock::where('stock_id', $data['productName'][$i])->get()`